# QT Access MainWindow SQLite Variable from Another Class

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, singleton

My app opens the SQLite database connection when the MainWindow launches and closes it when the MainWindow is destroyed.

How do I access the database connection from other classes.
I think I need to use a singleton format but haven't had any luck implementing it.

Here's what I have tried. It errors with.

```
C:\Users\cbennett\C++\CA_Letter_Generator\letter.cpp:9: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
     QSqlQuery qLetter = MainWindow.getDB().selectAll("letters","ltID=" + QString::number(ID));
                                   ^
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    loadButtons();
    this->adjustSize();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    db.close();
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::loadButtons(){
    db.setDatabaseName(dbPath);
    db.open();       
    //load buttons from db
}
cc_sqlite MainWindow::getDB(){
    return db;
}
```

letter.cpp

```
Letter::Letter(int ID){
    QSqlQuery qLetter = MainWindow.getDB().selectAll("letters","ltID=" + QString::number(ID));
    while (qLetter.next()) {
            int id = qLetter.value(0).toInt();
            QString name = qLetter.value(1).toString();
            QString body = qLetter.value(2).toString();
            QString sal = qLetter.value(3).toString();
            qDebug() << id << name << body << sal;
    }
}
```

letter.h

```
#ifndef LETTER_H
#define LETTER_H
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "field.h"
#include "../CC_CPP/cc_sqlite.h"


class Letter
{
public:
    Letter();
    Letter(int ID);
private:
    vector<Field> vFields;

};

#endif // LETTER_H
```

Comment: `MainWindow.getDB()` Isn't MainWindow a pointer? So you would need `MainWindow->getDB()`

Comment: How does `Letter` know about `MainWindow`?

Comment: From your edit it seems that `Letter` has no connection to `MainWindow`.

Comment: ***I think I need to use a singleton format*** You don't need a singleton.

Comment: How do I create a connection to the MainWindow? When I changed the . to -> gave me the following error

Comment: C:\Users\cbennett\C++\CA_Letter_Generator\letter.cpp:9: error: expected primary-expression before '->' token
         QSqlQuery qLetter = MainWindow->getDB().selectAll("letters","ltID=" + QString::number(ID));
                                       ^

Comment: One way is to pass a pointer to the `MainWindow` to `Letter`. A second way is to do something like `MainWindow* pMainWindow = QCoreApplication::instance()->findChild<MainWindow>();`

Comment: Also you may just use `QSqlDatabase::database()` to get a connection to the database if you have just 1 database or use the connection name parameter if you have more. And then not have to use MainWindow at all. This example explains that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17408989/487892

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I was able to modify the class I use for accessing the database and should now be able to access the database from any class I need! Thanks!